# Issue using map find - map/set iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, find

```
t_map::const_iterator orderSearch = time.find(std::make_pair(log[i].ID, log[i].event));
if(orderSearch != time.end())
    orderTime = orderSearch->second;
```

I have an issue with the above code and have managed to narrow it down to the iterator I create. The exact error is kind of unhelpful because it breaks to xtree:273 and not my actual code, however it does give the error "map/set iterator not dereferencable".

I'm unsure why this is happening, I might be doing something glaringly wrong, any help would be great.

Oh, initially this searches an empty map, if that could be an issue.

Definition of t_map:

```
typedef std::map<std::pair<string, string>, time_t> t_map;
```

Comment: what's the definition of `t_map` type?

Comment: Updated the main question

Comment: search empty map is not an issue. so `time` is `t_map` type? and have you confirmed `log[i].ID, log[i].event` are valid? especially `i` value is in range?

Comment: Yup time is the same type as t_map. I know the ID and events are valid because I use it previously and they're accessed fine.

Comment: "it ***breaks*** to xtree:273" - so it's your debugger reporting "map/set iterator not dereferencable", not the compiler?  There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted... see http://ideone.com/kkxW9E for something similar.  Perhaps you have undefined behaviour / data corruption from earlier processing.

Comment: Strange, I think it is something to do with the earlier behaviours because even attempting to insert to the map causes the same error. Is there any way I can configure visual studio to give me a more specific error?

Comment: Fixed it! Turned out to be completely unrelated to what I thought it was originally, and was actually code far far below. I love C++. Thanks for your help anyway, guys.

Comment: Next time post something a bit more complete so that others can compile it instead of guessing.  Glad you found it though.